# How to fill array by columns, not rows?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to make a 2d array 10 by 10 that looks like this:

```
0 45 44 42 39 35 30 24 17 9
0 0  43 41 38 34 29 23 16 8
0 0  0  40 37 33 28 22 15 7
0 0  0  0  36 32 27 21 14 6
0 0  0  0  0  31 26 20 13 5
0 0  0  0  0  0  25 19 12 4
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  18 11 3
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  10 2
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = new int [10][10];
        int i = 45;
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                if (row>col-1) {
                    System.out.print("0" + "  ");
                } else {
                    a[row][col]=i--;
                    System.out.print(a[row][col]+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result it prints in the console:

```
0  45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37
0  0  36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29
0  0  0  28 27 26 25 24 23 22
0  0  0  0  21 20 19 18 17 16
0  0  0  0  0  15 14 13 12 11
0  0  0  0  0  0  10 9  8  7 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  5  4 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  2 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I tried to change the order of inner and outer for loops, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What is your question? What didn't work when you changed the order of inner and outer loops? What code did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating normally, do it in reverse from the bottom right corner up and to the left.

- use nested loops.
- initialize a value to 1.
- then iterate as suggested, adjusting as shown in the code.
- assign the value to the cell and increment.

```
int [][] m = new int[10][10];
int value = 1;
for (int col = 9; col >= 0; col-- ) {
for (int row = col-1; row >= 0; row--) {
        m[row][col] = value++;  
    }
}

for (int[] row : m) {
    for (int i : row) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
  0 45 44 42 39 35 30 24 17  9
  0  0 43 41 38 34 29 23 16  8
  0  0  0 40 37 33 28 22 15  7
  0  0  0  0 36 32 27 21 14  6
  0  0  0  0  0 31 26 20 13  5
  0  0  0  0  0  0 25 19 12  4
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 18 11  3
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  2
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```